# Ionic App with Laravel 5 Backend

Tags: angularjs, laravel, ionic-framework

I'm having trouble with Laravel 5. I'm getting csrf token but i cant able to post. For registering purpose I'm trying post. But it is showing the token mismatch.

**Post method**

```
 var registerData = {
    'name':customer.name,
    'email':customer.email,
    'password' :customer.password,
    '_token' : customer._token
};
  alert(registerData._token);
$http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'http://192.168.0.112/grubsouk/grub/customer',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                 data : registerData
})
.success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    alert("success");
    $location.url("/sign");
})
.error(function(data){
    alert("error");                
})
```

**Get method**

```
$http.get('http://192.168.0.112/grubsouk/admin/getcsrf')
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
      alert("**** SUCCESS ****");
       alert(data.token);
      $rootScope.token = data.token;
      $rootScope.customer = {
        _token : $rootScope.token
    }
      alert(data.token);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
      alert("**** ERROR ****");
      alert(status);
    })
    $state.go('registration');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your Controller

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
```

Comment: where this should be add? get and post are in same controller.

Comment: Sorry iam new to coding. so please help me to get that

Comment: Post your server side controller

Comment: Please tell me what changes will be in my ionic app

Comment: i didnt getting @sathish ravepati

Comment: PLease Give me a solution

Comment: i did it in the server. but i'm getting same token every time in ionic. what should i do?